# Issue related to Background-Position for Image in HTML in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have following CSS class :

```
 .acceptRejectAll a, .acceptRejectAll a:visited{
        background-image: url("../images/view-patient.png");
        background-position: left top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color: #4B555C;
        float: left;
        height: 35px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 100px;  
  }
```

and following HTML :

```
<div style="float: none; display: inline-table" class="acceptRejectAll">
    <a style="display:inline-block;height:25px;" href="#" class="fontBlack" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAcceptAll">Accept All</a>
</div>
```

this is display as follows :

[image]

when i decrease the size of in css class like : `width : 85px`
it displays as follows :

[image]

it cuts image from right side:

i tried to set `background-Position`  in css class : but either left side or right side, image is not display correctly

wht is solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `background-size` for this. Example:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Please note that this setting can scale your image to fill parent.

Answer (score 1):

As the image is 100px (at least the visible part is about 92px so I guess the size is 100px) if you change the size of the button you need to scale the background image rather than change the position.

```
background-size:85px 35px;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Gradient and Border radius

Another way to approach this — considering the kind of button style you are using — is to go the gradient and border radius route. Whilst the code to use a css gradient looks rather messy, it is dynamically generated so you wont end up with stretched curved corners like you will using `background-size`.

Everything used below is pretty well supported now by most browsers. For anything that doesn't support the gradient you will get a solid blue background with curved corners instead, and it almost isn't worth worrying about non-support for border radius any more.

**markup:**

```
<div class="acceptRejectAll">
  <a href="#" class="fontBlack">Accept All</a>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.acceptRejectAll {
  display: inline-table;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px; /* You can change the width as you like */
  background: #c3e5fe; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c3e5fe 0%, #98d1fd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c3e5fe), color-stop(100%,#98d1fd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3e5fe 0%,#98d1fd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c3e5fe 0%,#98d1fd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c3e5fe 0%,#98d1fd 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3e5fe 0%,#98d1fd 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c3e5fe', endColorstr='#98d1fd',GradientType=0 );
}

.fontBlack {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

The gradient was generated using:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#c3e5fe+0,98d1fd+100;Custom

You end up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/NDHtn/

Or as a preview:

[image: preview of button]

#### When you must use an image

If there is no other choice but to use an image as a background for a button — say, the graphics are too complicated to replicate using css effects — rather than use one image stretched and distorted to fit, you can use something like the following. There are many ways to essentially achieve the same result, I prefer to keep my mark-up simple and my css more complicated (rather than the other way around). However, to make things more supportive of the wider browser community you can break your mark-up into three parts, rather than make use of `::before` and `::after`:

**markup:**

```
<a class="button" href="#">
  <span>Round Button with lots of text and then some</span>
</a>
```

**css:**

```
.button:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: url('image.png') left top;
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 99px;
}

.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: url('image.png') right top;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 99px;
}

.button {
  background: url('image.png') center -99px;
  height: 99px;
  margin: 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button span { display: block; padding: 35px 0px; }
```

**image.png**, hacked together using this [original image](http://oi45.tinypic.com/9hrh2d.jpg) and [pixlr.com](http://pixlr.com/editor/):

[image: image.png]

Which will give:

http://jsfiddle.net/2K5Kg/1/

[image: final result]

Example mark-up without use of psuedo elements:

```
<a class="button" href="#">
  <span class="before"></span>
  <span class="after"></span>
  <span>Round Button with lots of text and then some</span>
</a>
```

Then in the css just replace the `.button:before` with `.button .before` and the same for `:after`.